# Unable to encrypt and decrypt a file with a consistent naming

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, pycrypto

I have a file which stores user credentials.I plan to encrypt it once and then do the process of decryption and encryption subsequently whenever I need to fetch the credentials from the file.Below is the content of my original file

```
{"customer1": {"tool_id": "earth", "user": "myuser", "pwd": "mypwd", "acc_id": "myaccount", "app_id": "myapp"}}
{"customer2": {"tool_id": "venus", "app_id": "myapp2", "api_key": "mykey"}}
```

I have the below program to do the encryption and decryption

```
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random


def encrypt(key, filename):
    chunksize = 64 * 1024
    outputFile = "credentials.txt"
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
    IV = Random.new().read(16)

    encryptor = AES.new(getKey(key), AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(filesize.encode('utf-8'))
            outfile.write(IV)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += b' ' * (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))


def decrypt(key, filename):
    chunksize = 64 * 1024
    outputFile = filename

    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        filesize = int(infile.read(16))
        IV = infile.read(16)

        decryptor = AES.new(getKey(key), AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

        with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break

                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))
            outfile.truncate(filesize)


def getKey(password):
    hasher = SHA256.new(password.encode('utf-8'))
    return hasher.digest()
```

I plan to use the same naming conventions for my file for the encryption and decryption.

When I do encryption for the first time

```
encrypt("poplo1234", "credentials.txt")
```

It is able to do the encryption ( for the same filename)

When I try to decrypt it

```
decrypt("poplo1234", "credentials.txt")
```

It is unable to do it.However while encrypting, if I specify a different filename for the new file generated and do a decryption on that, it works just fine.

Why am I encountering such behaviour?How can I ensure the same filename is used for encryption and decryption multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is trying to read and write to the same file at the same time. The solution is to write to a temp file and after closing the files rename the temp file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that works for me! The script takes a zip file etc. hello.zip encrypt it with the name hello.zip.enc and after that decrypt it with the name hello_end.zip.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = '0123456789abcdef'
IV = 16 * '\x00'         # Initialization vector: discussed later
mode = AES.MODE_CFB
encryptor = AES.new(key, mode, IV=IV)

file = open("hello.zip", "rb")
text = file.read()
file.close()
ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)

encr_file = open("hello.zip.enc", "wb")
encr_file.write(ciphertext)
encr_file.close()


final_file = open("hello.zip.enc", "rb")
xen_text = final_file.read()
plaintext = encryptor.decrypt(xen_text)
final_file.close()


end = open("hello_end.zip", "wb")
end.write(plaintext)
end.close()
```

Use CFB mode in order not to mess around with padding